# Error when adding new field to existing model in Django on Elastic Beanstalk using RDS

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, rds

I'm getting an error when I try to add a new field to an existing model in Django. It's hosted on elastic beanstalk using a MySQL RDS database.

Here's the error when I try to access the model containing the new field:

(1054, "Unknown column 'existing_model.new_field' in 'field list'")

Is there a better way to treat migrations in Django on EB? Here's my .config file:

```
container_commands:
  01_makemigrations:
    command: "source /opt/python/run/venv/bin/activate && python manage.py makemigrations --noinput"
    leader_only: true
  02_migrate:
    command: "source /opt/python/run/venv/bin/activate && python manage.py migrate --noinput"
    leader_only: true
  03_createsu:
    command: "source /opt/python/run/venv/bin/activate && python manage.py createsu"
    leader_only: true
  04_collectstatic:
    command: "source /opt/python/run/venv/bin/activate && python manage.py collectstatic --noinput"
```

Any help? Thanks!

Comment: You need to run makemigrations and migrate to update your database structure...the field does not exist.

Comment: @cdvv7788 Yep I did, I just included my .config file in the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I had to run `python manage.py makemigrations` locally before `eb deploy`. That way, the migration files are created and when `migrate` is ran on the eb instance, it knows how to change the database accordingly.

My .config file is now:

```
container_commands:
  01_migrate:
    command: "source /opt/python/run/venv/bin/activate && python manage.py migrate --noinput"
    leader_only: true
  02_createsu:
    command: "source /opt/python/run/venv/bin/activate && python manage.py createsu"
    leader_only: true
  03_collectstatic:
    command: "source /opt/python/run/venv/bin/activate && python manage.py collectstatic --noinput"
```